# Cannot run convolutional.py in anaconda tenserenv

Tags: python, cuda

I have installed tensorflow in an anaconda environment called tensorenv and to test the installation I tried to run one of the examples convolutional.py and the follwing comes up.

```
Initialized!
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:346] Loaded cudnn library: 5005 but source was compiled against 4007.  If using a binary install, upgrade your cudnn library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded matches the version you specified during compile configuration.
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:457] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After initialized it should start the training but this error comes up. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux). The package version requires Cudnnv4. So either

- you switch to cudnnv4
- you install tensorflow from source as indicated in the link above

Comment: I have checked I have v5 of cudnn . I think this is the problem, as it is expecting v4. How to specify that I use v5??

Comment: Read the [tensorflow installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux). You have to install a version from source...